# Set variable in constructor failed?

Tags: c++, variables, constructor

The GetModel() function should return a model with 36 indices, but it returns a model with 0 indices.

After compiling: 0 Errors, 0 Warnings.

I know this forum hates beginners, but please be polite.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Model model;
    for (int i = 0; i < 36; i++) {
        model.indices.push_back(i);
    }

    Class cl(model);
    std::cout << cl.GetModel().indices.size() << std::endl; // should output 36 but outputs 0
}
```

**Class:** [I think in the counstructor of this class is the error]

```
class Class
{
public:
    Class(Model model){
        m_model = model;

        std::cout << model.indices.size() << std::endl; //output: 36
        std::cout << m_mesh.GetModel().indices.size() << std::endl; //output: 36
    }

    inline Model GetModel() { return m_model; } //m_model.indices.size() should be 36, but is 0

protected:
private:
    Model m_model;
};
```

**Model class:**

```
class Model
{
public:
    Model(const std::vector<unsigned int>& indices) {
        this->indices = indices;
    }
    Model(){}

    std::vector<unsigned int> indices;

    Model(const Model& other) {}
    void operator = (const Model& other) {}
```

Comment: `void operator = (const Model& other) {}` Where's the function body?

Comment: @JohnnyMopp this: {} (It has none.)

Comment: Your next step should have been to put `std::cout << m_model.indices.size()` in the ctor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with

```
Model(const Model& other) {}
void operator = (const Model& other) {}
```

This does not make them do the default behavior.

```
Model(const Model& other) {}
```

Will make a `Model` where `indices` is default initialized (zero sized), instead of copying from `other`.

```
void operator = (const Model& other) {}
```

Just does nothing.  To fix this just get rid of them since the class is copy constructable by default.

Comment: Thanks a lot!, I despaired of the last hours, and now I have the answer in 10 seconds. :D